# Do supremum and infimum work as if they're linear operators?

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen quite a lot of true statements of the form $ \sup(cA) = c \times  \sup(A)$, and $\sup (X \cup Y) = \sup(X) + \sup(Y) $. These are making me think if it's the case that the supremum and infimum work as if they are linear operators, or at least if there exist certain conditions under which they work as a linear operator.

Comment: The formula $\sup(cA)=c\sup(A)$ works only if $c\geq 0$ and the second formula is plain wrong: We in fact have $\sup(X\cup Y)=\max(\sup(X),\sup(Y))$. What you may have meant is that $\sup(X+Y)=\sup(X)+\sup(Y)$. They do behave like linear operators in the sense that some "set operations" correspond to "number operations" (not the vector space operations, though).

Comment: there are infinitely many cases when the formula $\sup (X \cup Y) = \sup(X) + \sup(Y)$ is correct, just take any $X,Y$ with $\sup(X)\ge\sup(Y)=0$ (or with $\sup(Y)\ge\sup(X)=0$) ... @LuizCordeiro